# Minimal polynomial of an endomorphism.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Let $V$ be a 4-dimensional Vector Space over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $f\in(\text{End}(V))$ be an endomorphism of V such that $f^4-2f^3+f^2=0$.

Determine the minimal polinomials of $f$ in these cases:

1) $f$ has only one eigenvalue;

2) $0$ and $1$ are eigenvalues with the same geometric multiplicity.

3)$\exists v$ such that $\{v,f(v),f^2(v),f^3(v)\}$ is a basis of $V$.

I thought about using the Hamilton-Cayley theorem which says that if $f^4-2f^3+f^2=0$ then the characteristic polynomial of $f$ is $x^4-2x^3+x^2 = x^2(x-1)^2$.

Now I don't know how to proceed. If this is the characteristic polynomial, how can $f$ has only an eigenvalue?

And also, what about the third question?

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: The Cayley-Hamilton does NOT say what you assert: check it out. This is about minimal polynomials. Note that $V$ may not have dimension $4$.Anyway you've got one polynomial satisfied by $f$; could you write down all possible minimal polynomials and take it from there?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that the space is 4-dimensional. By the way, if we know that $f^3-2f^3+f^2$=0, how is it correlated to the characteristic polynomial? 

By the way, if we say that $A$ is the associated matrix of $f$ and we know that $f^4-2f^3+f^2=0$, we know also that $A^4-2A^3+A^2=0$ so why can't we say that $x^4-2x^3+x^2$ is the characteristic polynomial? (Sorry for my question, I just started practicing with these things).

Comment: Also, we know that the minimal polynomial divides the characteristical one and it is the generator of the ideal $I(f)$. If $x^4-2x^3+x^2$ is in the ideal, there must be at least $x(x-1)$, is it true?

Comment: Better edit the question and specify the dimension. In general what CH says is that the minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial. So under your hypothesis we could for example have $f=I$ which satisfies $x^2(x-1)^2$, but whose characteristic polynomial is $(x-1)^4$. For this question concentrate on the minimal polynomial.

Comment: So, saying this, I can conclude that for the first point we have that the minimal polynomials are $x, x^2, x-1, (x-1)^2$? And for the second one it's $x(x-1)$ and $x^2(x-1)^2$? By the way I don't know how to proceed with the third.

Comment: I think that's right. For the last bit surely you can work out the matrix of $f$ wrt the given basis? The it's easy to see that the minl polynomial is ...

Comment: How can I work out the matrix of f?

Comment: With basis as given,label them $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4$. Then $f(e_1)=e_2$ and so the first column of the matrix is $(0,1,0,0)^{T}$. Now the second, now the third: but the fourth, well maybe the given property of $f$ will help ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) and 2) seem to be settled, if you need hints for those please post them here.

For 3): You already know that the minimal polynomial is a divisor of $x^4-2x^3+x^2$, therefore, it has degree at most $4$.

Now, if you assume by contradiction that the minimal polynomial $$P(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cX+d$$
has degree at most $3$, you can show that
$$af^3(v)+bf^2(v)+cf(v)+dv=0$$ 
which contradicts the fact that the vectors form a basis.